# Swiping objects diagonally

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swipe

I’m making an app and I need to make an object move when you swipe, however it’s not supposed to just follow you finger but move by a specific line. Say i’ve got a line going from the bottom left to top right, I want say a label to move along that line as you swipe in that direction, however it would be nearly impossible to swipe exactly on the line. So even if you’re not swiping on the line but next to it the label will still stay on the line.

I’d rather not use sprite kit (or any other kit) for this since I don’t think that would be necessary, I think I only need an action that will detect what coordinate you’re touching (whilst you are touching it) and then it would be relatively easy to calculate where the label is supposed to be moved to.

If you don’t quite understand what i mean please ask instead of not answering since I’m still not very familiar to programming and its terminology ;)

Comment: You know what you want so do some research before you ask something here. No one will write all of the code for you! Do it yourself

Comment: Well I have done some research, a lot in fact. I don’t think you can expect a 14 y/o kid who has never had any education regarding programming or anything about computers to just figure out everything on his own. I’ve read tutorials and guides about it for hours. Also if you’d read my question you would have known that I only wanted to know how to make/use that action I was talking about. Next time you could react a little nicer. @Bas

Comment: since you already did it in Objective-C you can do it in swift. Since Gesture Recognizers both use UIKit so you just need to change the syntax to make it work in Swift

Comment: if you typed in on google: swift gesture recognizer you would come up with multiple hits. Here is a link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: I didn’t say I’d done the whole app in objective-c, I only said I had moved objects in objective-c but that it was a long time ago. I still only need to know how to get the coordinates in a variable in the way I explained earlier.

Comment: Did you even read my comment? I said that I had done hours of research but i didn’t find what I needed so it doesn’t help to post a stupid google post... @Bas

Comment: Since you don't want to follow tutorials I posted you an answer. @Mats

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the `touchesBegan` method.
You can get the coordinates of your touch with the following code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
    var point = touch?.locationInView(self.view)

    println(point)
}
```

This will print out the location where you tapped the screen.

The coordinates where you tapped the screen are stored in the variable `point`

Comment: The reason this doesn't work for me is because i need the coordinates to update as you're moving your finger, thats why i asked here and didn't just follow the tutorial.

Comment: @Mats you didn't mention that in your question!

Comment: "I only need an action that will detect what coordinate you’re touching **(whilst you are touching it)**" is what i said @Bas